# Can the phrase "extended all the way up" be used to describe very tall objects?

Tags: phrases, expressions

According to [my](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tress%20extended%20all%22#psj=1&q=%22extended%20all%20the%20way%20up%22&start=10&tbm=bks) search, I think the phrase "extended all the way up" is usually to refer to things that are *spread until a certain location.*

Can this phrase be used to refer to a very tall object?

For example:

> The coniferous trees extended all the way up to the sky.

Or is there a better phrase to use in situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “The X extended all the way up to Y”, *[extended](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extended#Verb)* is the simple past tense or the past participle of the verb  *[extend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extend#Verb)*, whose principle meaning is to increase in extent, or to cause to increase in extent.  Thus, if you are describing a circumstance where some spruce, fir, or pine trees suddenly grew tall, all the way up to the sky, your original sentence would be perfectly appropriate.  If that's not what you mean to say, and want to guard against perverse readings, consider a form like “The X reached clear to Y” or “The X stretched up to Y”.  (Of course, like *extended* in your original sentence, the verbs  *reached* and *stretched* might be interpreted as expressing active growth, instead of meaning *[spanned](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/span#Verb)*; but such readings with the latter two verbs are slightly less likely than with the first one.)